# Similarity dimension and Hausdorff dimension

Tags: reference-request, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

How do we prove the similarity dimension equals the Hausdorff dimension if the self-similar set satisfies the open set condition? Which article contains this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open set condition, and it use to establish Hausdorff dimension, is due to

*Moran, P. A. P.*, Additive functions of intervals and Hausdorff measure, Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 42, 15-23 (1946). [ZBL0063.04088](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0063.04088).

Moran was a student of Besicovitch at Cambridge at the time.

**plug**
 Section 6.5 in
*Edgar, Gerald*, Measure, topology, and fractal geometry, Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics, 2nd ed. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-0-387-74748-4/hbk). xv, 268 p. (2008). [ZBL1152.28008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1152.28008).

Comment: +1 Can I also suggest Hutchinson's 1981 paper as a pretty approachable introduction to self-similar fractal sets?  That tends to be the one that I recommend to clever undergrads as a good introduction.  And, as long as I am here, thank you for your book, Dr Edgar.  It was one of my first tastes of fractal geometry.  (Though I miss the first edition, in which all of the proofs ended with happy little smiley faces.  What happened to those?)