# Is the filled Sierpinski Curve (Gasket, Square...) a fractal?

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

This is regarding the area enclosed by the Sierspinski curve as shown white(!) in the added image. I get a Hausdorff dimension of this shape equal to 2, which is the same as the topological dimension. But I thought this was a fractal, is it not?

[image: The Sierpinski curve for a few iterations.]

Here's some background (and my understanding):

The Hausdorff dimension is equal to the similarity dimension when the self-similar object satisfies the open set condition (perfect self-similarity) [E.g. source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265266/similarity-dimension-and-hausdorff-dimension). The object in the image above seems to not be perfectly self-similar when the iteration goes to infinity, as it has 4 copies of itself connected through a central box. However, the area of this central box rapidly goes towards zero, making it ~perfectly self-similar in the infinite fractal iteration limit. This would give a Hausdorff dimension equal to $log_2(4) = 2$.

The topological dimension is also 2.

However, Mandelbrot writes in his *The Fractal Geometry of Nature* (1982).

> A fractal is by definition a set for which the Hausdorff Besicovitch dimension strictly exceeds the topological dimension.

So I'm a bit confused. The areas enclosed by e.g. the Sierpinski square or the Sierpinski curve have Hausdorff dimensionality equal to 2. So are these areas not fractals?

Kind regards,
Fredrik

**EDIT 1:**
Maybe it not valid to ignore the contribution from the central square? The same type of central square is repeated in all the smaller copies as well. Maybe it is not negligible?

**EDIT 2:**
The open set condition formulation used is:  The set of self similiar objects $\{S_0, \dots S_N\}$ constituting e.g. a fractal,satisfies the open set condition if there exists a non-empty open set $O$ such that $Si(O)$ are pairwise disjoint and contained in $O$.
Explicitly written
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &S_i(O) \subset O \;\; \forall \; i \in\left[0, N\right], \;\; \text{and}\\
        &S_i(O) \cap S_i(O) = \emptyset \;\; \text{if} \;\; i = j.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
[As formulated here](https://jameshbailie.github.io/Papers/papers/Hausdorff.pdf)

Comment: Since you cite the 1982 edition of the text, I would suggest that you read the section on page 458, titled "The Definition of 'Fractal'".  That being said, if you take "fractal" to mean a set which has different Hausdorff and topological definitions, spaces with equal Hausdorff and topological dimensions are, by definition, not fractal.  I'm not sure what you gain (or lose) by placing things in the categories "fractal" and "not fractal", but that is how the definition reads.

Comment: That being said, several of the examples you give have non-integer Hausdorff dimension.  For example, the usual Sierpinski gasket has Hausdorff dimension $\log(3)/\log(2) \approx 1.585$, and the Sierpinski carpet has Hausdorff dimension $\log(8)/\log(3) \approx 1.893$.

Comment: Also, now that I look at this again, I don't think that your object is the attractor of an iterated function system which satisfies the open set condition.  It appears to me that if you were to describe the set as the attractor of an iterated function system, it would be a system with five maps, each of which has a scaling factor of a bit more than a third.  This system fails to satisfy the OSC.  It also appears to me that the attractor of this system is a square, which is not generally considered "fractal".

Comment: Thanks for the reply @XanderHenderson :) 

I guess there's not really a good and intuitive definition of a fractal. I don't see the chapter you're referring too, however, I see that in a later edition, Mandelbrot also commented that he had not found a good definition for a fractal, and that his own excluded objects that he meant should be considered fractals.

Sierpinski carpet and Sierpinski square are different objects. The square looks pretty much just as the curve though:)

Comment: Also, on on the OSC definition, then hm maybe. I have used the definition that the set of similitudes S satisfies the open set condition if there exists a non-empty open set O such that Si(O) are pairwise disjoint and contained in O. So a definition not formulated directly as a dynamical system.

Comment: What is $\operatorname{Si}(O)$?

Comment: It's the set of similitudes, so smaller "pieces" constituting a self-similar object, which are necessarily themselves self-similar

Comment: As you have written it, each $S_i$ should be a contracting similitude, hence the collection of similitudes is an iterated function system.  What are these maps?  What is the open set?